# Issues developing complex Yup validation for Formik form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have a complex Formik form that I'm trying to apply validations to. My current schema is below:

```
const applyPaymentFormValidation = yup.object().shape({
  payments: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      applied: yup
        .number(),
    })
  ),
  newPayments: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      total: yup.number(),
      paymentType: yup.number().required("Select a payment method"),
      date: yup
        .date()
        .required("A date must be provided")
        .max(tomorrow, "You cannot future date a transaction"),
      paymentNumber: yup.string().nullable(),
    })
  ),
  invoiceLines: yup.array().of(
    yup.object()
      .shape({
        clientAmountPaid: yup
          .number()
          .required("You must provide a valid amount")
          .min(0, "You must provide a valid amount"),
        insurAmountDue: yup
          .number()
          .required("You must provide a valid amount")
          .min(0, "You must provide a valid amount"),
        writeOff: yup
          .number()
          .required("You must provide a valid amount")
          .min(0, "You must provide a valid amount"),
        amountDue: yup
          .number()
          .required("You must provide a valid amount")
          .min(0, "You must provide a valid amount"),
      })
      .test(
        "amountTest",
        "Client due + insurer due - writeoff must total up the the amount due",
        function (value) {
          return (
            defaultNullUndefined(value.clientAmountDue, 0) +
              defaultNullUndefined(value.insurAmountDue, 0) -
              defaultNullUndefined(value.writeOff, 0) ===
            defaultNullUndefined(value.amountDue, 0)
          );
        }
      )
      .test(
        "writeOffBelowTotalTest",
        "Cannot write off more than line total",
        function (value) {
          return (
            defaultNullUndefined(value.writeOff, 0) <=
            defaultNullUndefined(value.amountDue, 0)
          );
        }
      )
  ),
  // can you add .test here for tests across properties of the parent shape?
});
```

I'm trying to develop a validation to check if the sum of all invoiceLines.clientAmountDue equals the sum of all payments.applied. I added a comment towards the end of where I think this check goes, but I'm not sure the syntax. I tried a .test(), but again, couldn't quite get it. Any suggestions or resources I could reference for more insight?

As a follow up, I only need to validate newPayments if payments doesn't exist and vice versa. Is there a similar solution for that?

Here's my current test with the resulting error:

```
  .test("total_test", "total error", (payments: any, invoiceLines: any) => {
    let paymentsTotal = payments.reduce(
      (total: any, value: any) => total + value.applied
    );
    let invoiceLinesTotal = invoiceLines.reduce(
      (total: any, value: any) => total + value.clientAmountPaid
    );
    return paymentsTotal === invoiceLinesTotal;
  });
```

```
payments.reduce is not a function
TypeError: payments.reduce is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are get for an undefined variable. A variable with values is in 1 argument, do this:

```
.test("total_test", "total error", (values: any) => {
  let paymentsTotal = values.payments.reduce(
    (total: any, value: any) => total + value.applied
  );
  let invoiceLinesTotal = values.invoiceLines.reduce(
    (total: any, value: any) => total + value.clientAmountPaid
  );
  return paymentsTotal === invoiceLinesTotal;
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).